# Inserting values from Meteor into MongoDB got really slow

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, meteor

Inserting values from Meteor into MongoDB got unbelievable slow, the machine is not under any load.

- System: Mac OS El Capitan
- MongoDB version: 2.6.12 *(updated to 3.2)*
- Meteor: 1.4.2.3

I am getting a value from the db and remove the _id to generate a new one and insert the value again into the db.

```js
Meteor.methods({
  testInsert() {
    const id = ID.find({ Project: Number(287), ID: Number(169372), Deleted: false }).fetch();

    if (id === undefined || id === '' || id.length > 1 || id.length === 0) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('no unique id found');
    }

    console.log('got ID ' + id[0].ID);

    const oldId = id[0]._id;
    delete id[0]._id;

    try {
      console.log('Start inserting ... ' + new Date());
      ID.insert(id[0]);
      console.log('Done inserting ' + new Date());
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('error inserting`);
    }
    console.log('Done single');
  },
});
```

Result:

> got ID 169372
>
> Start inserting ... Fri Nov 18 2016 12:25:59 GMT+0100 (CET)
>
> Done inserting Fri Nov 18 2016 12:26:09 GMT+0100 (CET)

It takes 10 seconds to do an insert! The JSON I am inserting is 14kb big or rather small. The insert takes less than a second in the shell (command line) of mongo. This code used to be fast enough. I also have an index on the table.

```
ID._ensureIndex({ Deleted: 1, ID: 1 });
```

To be clear any insert is slow at the moment not just based on the sample code above. One strange thing though is that the load on the machine with node/meteor running goes to 100%, for a simple insert! Any ideas?

**Update:**

The MongoDB is not the running on my local developer machine but on a dedicated db server, I use a tunnel (if you are wondering why the error msg says localhost :) )

**Update 2:**

When I use a for loop to insert 10 IDs meteor crashes, although meteor recovers it takes 5-10 Minutes nonetheless it wrote actually all data

```
Exception while polling query {"collectionName":"id","selector":{"id":287,"Deleted":false},"options":{"transform":null}}: MongoError: connection 7 to localhost:27017 timed out
```

**Update 3:**

I updated the MongoDB to 3.2 but still getting an exception.

```
Exception while polling query {"collectionName":"ID","selector":{"ID":287,"Deleted":false},"options":{"transform":null}}: MongoError: connection 17 to localhost:27017 timed out
```

**Update 4:**

The polling errors/timeouts are unrelated to the issue I think, that is why I removed the stack traces. I was able to construct a generic test case to replicate the issue. It seems that the mongo node/meteor driver is not able to handle array properties well. I have inserted entries with the Java driver into mongo with no issues. I have created a test case which populates an array with 500 random entries. This insert statement takes roughly 10 seconds. By increasing the number of IDs you will also encounter the timeout errors.

```js
Meteor.methods({
  testInsert() {
    const testIDs = [
      { ID: 100000, array: [] },
      { ID: 200000, array: [] }];

   function makeTestCase(id) {
     for (let i = 0; i < 500; i += 1) {
       id.array.push({
         "Date": new Date,
         "Text1" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.",
         "Text2" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.",
         "Text3" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.",
         "Text4" : i,
         "Text5" : i,
         "Text6" : i,
         "Text7" : i,
       });
     }
   }

    testIDs.forEach(makeTestCase);

    function insertID(id) {
      try {
        console.log(`Start inserting ... ${new Date()}`);
        BshID.insert(id, { validate: false });
        console.log(`Done inserting ${new Date()}`);
      } catch (e) {
        throw new Meteor.Error('ID ERROR');
      }
    }

    testIDs.forEach(insertID);

    console.log('all done');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of improvements you can do:

#### **Create a descending index for the `ID` field**

If I correctly understood your code, you are always searching for the oldest record to generate the new document. If you create a descending index, the MongoDB will find you document faster because it will optimze your index to look first into the highest values of `ID`.
Also, if you are always searching by `Project` and `ID`, you should include the `Project` in the index as well.

First, remove your oldest index:
`ID._dropIndex({Deleted: 1, ID: 1})`

Then, create the new index: `ID._ensureIndex({Deleted: 1, ID: -1, Project: -1})`

#### Use findOne instead of find

If you just need one document, use `findOne` to find this document and MongoDB will not need to look into all your records to fetch the results. Also you can add the `fields` property to your `findOne` to tell Meteor only the fields that are relevant to you in this operation but seeing your example you are creating a copy of the document so its not the case.

```
ID.findOne({ 
  Project: Number(287), 
  ID: Number(169372), 
  Deleted: false 
});
```

#### **Extra: Update your MongoDB to 3.2**

You are using Meteor 1.4 so you should update your MongoDB to the appropriate version compatible with this Meteor version. Check http://info.meteor.com/blog/announcing-meteor-1.4 for more information.

**Further reading**

- https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/applications/indexes/

Comment: Hi Inmunhoz, thank you for your reaction! Some clarifications, yes you are right I only look at the newest entry but the ID field is not an incremental ID so the highest value != latest entry, sorry for not making that clear. 

The use of find is on purpose, as I want to know when there are more values in the DB then allowed. As I remove old entries by setting their property "deleted" to false, I sometimes encounter that ID's do not get updated and this is how I can catch those.

Comment: Regarding the MongoDB version I should have mentioned, that I do not use the developer DB which comes with meteor but a DB which is on a dedicated machine where only MongoDB is running and my expectation is that the meteor drivers for node do not have a limitation to only work with MongoDB > 3.2 right?

Comment: @user263367 The `pooling query` error its because of your MongoDB version. When you update to 3.2 its gonna work fine.

Comment: @user263367 Besides your implementation logic, you should update your indexes to use an ascending one in the `Project`, `ID` and `Deleted` fields. Your current index is not being used to fetch results because your compound index its just for the `Deleted` and `ID` field.

Comment: @user263367 Sorry, I mean descending.

Comment: Hi Inmunhoz, thanks again for your tips. Unfortunately, the pooling exception did not go away with the update to 3.2.